# Processing aggregation in pandas data frame based on constraint in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analysing data in excel which contains multiple columns. I have extracted out of those columns that I am analysing. based on some of the conditions of existing column, I would like to create a few new columns.

First of all, my sample data frame is as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Match'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B',]
df['HomeGoal'] = [ 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]
df['AwayGoal'] = [ 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]
df ['AOS'] = [0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06]
df ['% Prob'] = [0.15,0.12,0.10,0.08,0.05,0.18,0.15,0.10,0.08,0.05]
```

The data frame contains **Match**, **HomeGoal**,**AwayGoal**,**AOS** and **% Prob**.

I want to create the following columns

```
Homegoal <1
HomeGoal <2
HomeGoal <3
HomeGoal >=1
HomeGoal >=2
HomeGoal >=3
```

Each column contains the sum of % prob which meets the following conditions:

```
Homegoal <1 ==> sum of the colums % Prob where Homegoal less than 1
HomeGoal <2 ==> sum of the colums % Prob where Homegoal less than 2
HomeGoal <3 ==> sum of the colums % Prob where Homegoal less than 3
HomeGoal >=1 ==> sum of the colums % Prob and AOS where Homegoal 1 goals and above
HomeGoal >=2 ===> sum of the colums % Prob and AOS where Homegoal 2 goals and above
HomeGoal >=3 ==> sum of the colums % Prob and AOS where Homegoal 2 goals and above
```

All these calculation mentioned above is based on each match.

May I get your advice how to do it?

I have attached the expected outcome as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
L = [1,2,3]

for v in L:
    #new column name 
    col = 'HG>={}'.format(v)
    #filter by condition
    df1 =  df[df['HomeGoal'] >= v]
    #new Series filled by aggregated values per groups and added column AOS
    df[col] = df1.groupby('Match')['% Prob'].transform('sum') + df['AOS']
    #only first non missing value per group
    mask = ~df.dropna(subset=[col]).duplicated(subset=[col, 'Match']) 
    df[col] = df[col].mask(~mask, 0)

for v in L:
    col = 'HG>{}'.format(v)
    df[col] = df[df['HomeGoal'] < v].groupby('Match')['% Prob'].transform('sum')
    mask = ~df.dropna(subset=[col]).duplicated(subset=[col, 'Match']) 
    df[col] = df[col].mask(~mask, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)

  Match  HomeGoal  AwayGoal   AOS  % Prob  HG>=1  HG>=2  HG>=3  HG>1  HG>2  \
0     A         0         0  0.12    0.15   0.00   0.00   0.00  0.15  0.27   
1     A         1         1  0.12    0.12   0.47   0.00   0.00  0.00  0.00   
2     A         2         2  0.12    0.10   0.00   0.35   0.00  0.00  0.00   
3     A         3         3  0.12    0.08   0.00   0.00   0.25  0.00  0.00   
4     A         4         4  0.12    0.05   0.00   0.00   0.00  0.00  0.00   
5     B         0         0  0.06    0.18   0.00   0.00   0.00  0.18  0.33   
6     B         1         1  0.06    0.15   0.44   0.00   0.00  0.00  0.00   
7     B         2         2  0.06    0.10   0.00   0.29   0.00  0.00  0.00   
8     B         3         3  0.06    0.08   0.00   0.00   0.19  0.00  0.00   
9     B         4         4  0.06    0.05   0.00   0.00   0.00  0.00  0.00   

   HG>3  
0  0.37  
1  0.00  
2  0.00  
3  0.00  
4  0.00  
5  0.43  
6  0.00  
7  0.00  
8  0.00  
9  0.00
```

Comment: Thanks Jez. I will try it with my data as I am out stationed now.

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: @koPytok - Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `numpy.where`
Example for 1:

```
import numpy as np
df['HG>=1'] = np.where(df['HomeGoal']>=1, 
    'insert your pass condition logic calculation here', 
    'insert your fail condition logic calculation here')
```

I do not understand your pass/fail logic calculations, so you will have to provide that or input them yourself.

Comment: Fails is considered to be zero. But I have provided the pass condition, which is an aggregation.

Comment: How did you calculate index row `6` column `HG>=1`? I got `0.05 + 0.08 + 0.10 + 0.15 + 0.06 = 0.44` instead of `0.48` that is in your screenshot. If you have done it on Excel, why not just post your Excel formula?

Comment: Sorry, It was my calculation error. it should be 0.44. Thanks.